# Parse json with PHP. Getting Undefined property: stdClass errors

Tags: php, json

I am having some issues parsing a json file from Jenkins using PHP

```
    {
  "actions" : [
    {
      "causes" : [
        {
          "shortDescription" : "Started by an SCM change"
        }
      ]
    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {
      "buildsByBranchName" : {
        "origin/release_5.6.0" : {
          "buildNumber" : 242,
          "buildResult" : null,
          "marked" : {
            "SHA1" : "fde4cfd86b8511d328037b9e9c55876007bb6e67",
            "branch" : [
              {
                "SHA1" : "fde4cfd86b8511d328037b9e9c55876007bb6e67",
                "name" : "origin/release_5.6.0"
              }
            ]
          },
          "revision" : {
            "SHA1" : "fde4cfd86b8511d328037b9e9c55876007bb6e67",
            "branch" : [
              {
                "SHA1" : "fde4cfd86b8511d328037b9e9c55876007bb6e67",
                "name" : "origin/release_5.6.0"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "origin/release_5.7.0" : {
          "buildNumber" : 315,
          "buildResult" : null,
          "marked" : {
            "SHA1" : "ae2cbf69a25e0632e0f1d3eeb27a907b154efce0",
            "branch" : [
              {
                "SHA1" : "ae2cbf69a25e0632e0f1d3eeb27a907b154efce0",
                "name" : "origin/release_5.7.0"
              }
            ]
          },
          "revision" : {
            "SHA1" : "ae2cbf69a25e0632e0f1d3eeb27a907b154efce0",
            "branch" : [
              {
                "SHA1" : "ae2cbf69a25e0632e0f1d3eeb27a907b154efce0",
                "name" : "origin/release_5.7.0"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
```

I have tried doing the following

```
//Read in JSON object
$json_file2 = file_get_contents('url.com/json');
//Decode JSON file
$test = json_decode($json_file2); //object
//print_r($json_file2);

echo $test->causes;
```

I am also trying to access the different sections in "buildsByBranchName".  I have tried many different variations of the code above, but I keep getting "Undefined property: stdClass" errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not accessing that value properly. `causes` resides under `actions` which is an array. Your code also won't work because `causes` is an array.

```
// This is an array so you can't use echo here.
$causes = $test->actions[0]->causes; 

// echo out the shortDescription
echo $causes[0]->shortDescription;
```

or

```
echo $test->actions[0]->causes[0]->shortDescription;
```

Comment: I just seen what you added, the last line of code works. Also what about accessing the "buildsByBranchName" section?

Comment: I tried the following, but no luck.    

$version = "origin/release_5.6.0";


echo $test->actions[0]->causes[0]->buildsByBranchName[0]->$version->buildNumber;

Comment: `buildsByBranchName` is not under `causes`

Comment: Still getting an error (Undefined property: stdClass::$buildsByBranchName).  Using the following below.

$version = "origin/release_5.6.0";

echo $test->actions[0]->buildsByBranchName->$version->buildNumber;

Comment: I think I am having an issue because of the empty brackets in the Json above buildsByBranchName.

Comment: It's hard for me to help because I can't set up the scenario since it seems all of the JSON is not present. All of the above fails for me as a result.